# How to create a 'Current Day' button using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, button

I am currently building a scheduling app that has a previous day, current day and next day button. How would I create a current day button?

HTML File

```
    <button type="button" (click)="previousDay()" >Left</button> 
    <br>
    <h2>{{ currentDay }}</h2>
    <br>
    <button type="button" (click)="nextDay()" >Right</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" (click)="currentDay()" >Current Day</button>
    <br>
</div>
```

TypeScript File:

```
export class DayViewComponent implements OnInit {

  events: any[];
  currentDay: Date;
  modalActive: boolean = false;

  previousDay() {
    this.currentDay.setDate(this.currentDay.getDate()-1);
  }

  nextDay() {
    this.currentDay.setDate(this.currentDay.getDate()+1);
  } 

  currentDay(){

}
}
```

Comment: this.currentDay = new Date();

Answer (score 0):

I'd be careful about naming your functions. It's confusing to have `currentDay` to be a date *and* a function. How about prefixing your functions with 'set'?

```
    setCurrentDay() {
      this.currentDay = new Date()
    }
```